# Automatically load data via service

Tags: c#, .net

I am using MYSQL database. I have a table called pricing_detail in which amount is a field. this amount field is frequently changed by different user . At UI portion there is a page where i am displaying amount. I want a service which will run in the background. whenever value of the amount is changed in the database. new value of amount is instantly visible to all the users who opened this page at that time without any delay. I am confusing about  this weather this is it practically possible ? id possible than how my service know that the value is changed in the database and how this value is loaded to the browser?

Comment: well it a simple question just need guide line that what the stapes we have to follow in my cenerio

Comment: well and i ma asking this question in .net .

Comment: What did you do already?

Comment: well i am writing the cenerio in the post... I this this type of problem can arise with differnnt user. the person you dislike my post should think about it first and than dislike. if  they dont know the answer than they dont should have any right to dislike it

Comment: You should read this: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: well i dont want to ask question for publicity. I beleve that in this site question ask for whose who stuck in a problem and need solution. Now for those who only know the answer and post the question only for the points

Comment: So, what is your problem that you're stuck in?

Comment: yes that why i only post question

Comment: the person who dislike this question can please give me the reason to dislike it?

Comment: i think it a valid question..................

Answer (score 1):

As  your data is frequently changing,try to refresh the form every time so that the data which is changed will be updated.so use timer, trigger in update panel and assign some time for the timer so that for every particular interval form will be loaded again.

Timer:

```
<asp:Timer ID="timer" runat="server" Interval="5000"></asp:Timer>
```

Trigger :

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
         <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer" EventName="Tick" />
         </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```